# IE8 ignores "filter" CSS styles

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, filter

I have a page which uses the `AlphaImageLoader` CSS filter for IE8 like so:

> filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/images/thing.png', sizingMethod='scale');

In my test IE8 (Windows XP, factory settings), everything is fine. The client however received a screenshot from someone claiming to be also using IE8 which looks like the browser completely ignores the `filter` directive. All other styles in the IE-specific stylesheet loaded via conditional comments appear to be working. Is there any setting in IE or in Windows which would be causing this?

Thanks, Simon

Comment: It would be worth comfirming the customer is definitely on IE8, get a screengrab from them if possible. 
He could be running compatibility mode, or even an older version of IE - You should clear that question up before spending too much time thinking about the "possibilities"

Comment: That's a good idea, I'm doing that right now...

Comment: Update: I got confirmation that it is indeed IE8 and compatibility mode is off. This is weird...

Answer (score 6):

IE8 replaced `filter` with `-ms-filter`.

If you want to support all versions of IE, you need to provide both of these styles.

The syntax for `-ms-filter` is slightly different to `filter` as well:

- All filters are now specified with their full `progid` string (as per your example, but some filters could previously be specified with a shorter syntax).
- The value for `-ms-filter` must be enclosed in quotes. This is to prevent it from being invalid CSS syntax (since it contains a colon after `progid` it is invalid CSS; in bad cases has been known to cause parsing errors in other browsers that stop them from reading the rest of the CSS file properly).

So in your example, you need the following styles:

```
.myelement {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/images/thing.png', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/images/thing.png', sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

Note that IE9 has dropped support for both `filter` and `-ms-filter`, in favour of the equivalient standard CSS3 properties.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @thirtydot - it may work in some cases, but certainly not all cases. I didn't try this specific style, but there are definitely some which require both.

Answer (score 0):

This simple test case: http://fiddle.jshell.net/TyMxr/show/light/

```
<div></div>

div {
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 256px;
    height: 256px;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/74c04b6c96836f044ed927a5db4dc92b?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG', sizingMethod='scale');
}
```

works in IE6, IE7, IE8, IE9, and Quirks Mode in any of those versions.

I can't think of any reason this wouldn't work in IE.

Do you have a test page to look at? I think something else must be going on.