# Cross Browser image preview in Image upload section is not working in ie8

Tags: javascript, image, internet-explorer, upload, cross-browser

Image preview in upload image section in my site is not working in IE8+ browsers. But Working fine in IE7 and IE6. I am using this below code for image preview functionality.
**JS:**

```
var loadImageFile = (function () {
    if (window.FileReader) {
        var oPreviewImg = null, oFReader = new window.FileReader(),
            rFilter = /^(?:image\/bmp|image\/cis\-cod|image\/gif|image\/ief|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/pipeg|image\/png|image\/svg\+xml|image\/tiff|image\/x\-cmu\-raster|image\/x\-cmx|image\/x\-icon|image\/x\-portable\-anymap|image\/x\-portable\-bitmap|image\/x\-portable\-graymap|image\/x\-portable\-pixmap|image\/x\-rgb|image\/x\-xbitmap|image\/x\-xpixmap|image\/x\-xwindowdump)$/i;

        oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
            if (!oPreviewImg) {
                var newPreview = document.getElementById("imagePreview");
                oPreviewImg = new Image();
                oPreviewImg.style.width = (newPreview.offsetWidth).toString() + "px";
                oPreviewImg.style.height = (newPreview.offsetHeight).toString() + "px";
                newPreview.appendChild(oPreviewImg);
            }
            oPreviewImg.src = oFREvent.target.result;
        };

        return function () {
            var aFiles = document.getElementById("imageInput").files;
            if (aFiles.length === 0) { return; }
            if (!rFilter.test(aFiles[0].type)) { alert("You must select a valid image file!"); return; }
            oFReader.readAsDataURL(aFiles[0]);
        }

    }
    if (navigator.appName === "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
        return function () {
            document.getElementById("imagePreview").filters.item("DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader").src = document.getElementById("imageInput").value;

        }
    }
})();
```

**CSS Style:**

```
#imagePreview {
    width: 160px;
    height: 120px;
    float: right;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(sizingMethod=scale);
}
</style>
```

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="imagePreview"></div>

        <form name="uploadForm">
            <p><input id="imageInput" type="file" name="myPhoto" onchange="loadImageFile();"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Send"></p>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

This code runs in IE 6 and IE7 but not runs in IE8+. Anyone knows what is the issue in above code. Running example link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/files/3699/crossbrowser_image_preview.html

Comment: Whats the point of anonymous function if you are assigning it to a variable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE8 ignores "filter" CSS styles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593873/ie8-ignores-filter-css-styles)

Comment: is it something that needs to be imported in order to work in IE7  those filters 
 " .filters.item("DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader") " ?

Answer (score 1):

Please check this post:
[How to upload preview image before upload through JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094012/how-to-upload-preview-image-before-upload-through-javascript) 
I have tested, one thing must to do:

```
IE8 needs a security settings change: internet settings, security, custom level :

 [] Include local directory path when uploading files to a server
 ( ) Disable
 (o) Enable
```

After enable this option, your demo works fine in ie8! https://developer.mozilla.org/files/3699/crossbrowser_image_preview.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IE8 replaced filter with -ms-filter.
If you want to support IE7 and 8 both, you need to provide both of these styles.
The syntax for -ms-filter is slightly different to filter as well.

You might find more information here:
[IE8 ignores "filter" CSS styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593873/ie8-ignores-filter-css-styles)

Answer (score 0):

do as in this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23361822/get-image-hight-after-dximagetransform-microsoft-alphaimageloader/23511042#23511042)

whats missing on your code is the height and width setting

try with this

```
  imagePreview.style.width = "160px";
    imagePreview.style.height = "120px";
```

if the image size is bigger than the mentioend size it will not expand as you coding, change the `sizingMethod=scale` to `sizingMethod=image`