# Get image height after DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader

Tags: javascript, html

I have to show Images selected in File Upload conrtor before Submitting to the page.

Here is my code

CSS

```
 .upld
   {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(sizingMethod=image);            
   }
```

HTML

```
    <input type='file' onchange="getIt(this,'divImgTop1')" /> <br /> 
    <div class="upld" id="divImgTop1"></div>
```

javascript

```
function getIt(t,id) {                       
       var divShw = document.getElementById(id);          
       divShw.filters.item("DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader").src = t.value;         
       divShw.style.width = "100px";
       divShw.style.height = "100px";
     }
```

code is working fine and the image gets displayed.

**Question**
How can i find the height of the image displayed ?

Answer (score 0):

we need only  to make `position:absolute` on each `div`

then

```
$('#divImgTop1').height()
```

will give the height of the image :)