# How to set an background-image (using filter attribute) for IE8 using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

For Chrome and other browsers, we use

```
$('.dummyActive').live("click", function(event){

$('#imageClass').css("background-  image","url(web/M425/images/imgAcc/cards/"+arrayElement[this.id.match(/\d+/)]+") ");

});
```

Now, since background-size doesnt work with IE8,
I am using this CSS,

```
.imageClass{
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='web/M425/images/imgAcc/cards/summyImg.png',sizingMethod='scale')
}
```

and the above CSS works when i give it using CSS but I do not know how to set an image to a filter using jquery dynamically.

Now how do i set an image(for IE8) for the above dummyActive live function using javascript or JQuery.

So, i am trying to set filter attribute to dummyActive class(below peice of code) but its not working as i am using both kinds of inverted commas and double inverted commas.

$('.dummyActive').live("click", function(event){

```
$('#imageClass').css("filter","progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='web/M224/images/imgAcc/cards/"+arrayAccountImage[this.id.match(/\d+/)]+"',sizingMethod='scale'+")");

});
```

Comment: JQuery live() method deprecated since 1.7. so try using .on() method.

`$('dummyActive').on('click', function(){
    $('#imageClass').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');
});`

Comment: @SachinK thanks. But, what is the syntax for setting the above mentioned filter attribute to dummyClass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the CSS filter try "-ms-filter" instead of "filter"

[IE8 ignores "filter" CSS styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593873/ie8-ignores-filter-css-styles)

Comment: IE8 is picking up filter attribute, but now i need to set an image to .imageClass using jQuery as the names of the images can vary. So how do i set the filter attribute to the class in jquery @r00ster

Comment: Would you not just add the class with jQuery? `$(yourIMageSelector).addClass('imageClass')` [addClass Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

Comment: but the image can vary depending upon the selection of various images on the screen.

Comment: What is the criteria for the images that need to have the css class set?

Comment: There was a syntax error in the code which i mentioned. Thanks for the help @r00ster

Comment: Glad I could help! @nikhilesh